# Why is the parse_number function saying my character vector is not a character?

Tags: r, parsing, readr

I'm using R to pull out numbers from strings of ids. In the past, I've used readr's parse_number() function, but recently, I'm getting a bizarre error where it's saying that my character column is not character:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

test <- tibble(id_numbers = c("ICKLSD5", "DFTEM4", "DPDFE45"))

test %>%
  parse_number(id_numbers)


Error in parse_vector(x, col_number(), na = na, locale = locale, trim_ws = trim_ws) : 
  is.character(x) is not TRUE
```

But, the column is clearly a character vector:

```
#Yields true
is.character(test$id_numbers)
```

And, even wrapping the column in as.character still gives the same error:

```
test %>%
  parse_number(as.character(id_numbers))
```

I know there's other workarounds with other functions, but I really want to use parse_number(). Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: `%>%` will pass your tibble as the first argument to `parse_number()`.  Does `parse_number(test$id_numbers)` work?  Or do you want a new column, and need a `mutate(newcol = parse_number(id_numbers))`?

Comment: thank you both! I completely spaced on not having mutate in my call.

Comment: @MrFlick I believe you should post as an answer. The comment is short but potentially useful to others. There are 2 close as typo votes but it's not a typo, it's a misinterpretation of the function's usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't pipe your data frame directly into `parse_number`. You would need to pipe into a mutate:

```
test %>% mutate(id_numbers=parse_number(id_numbers))
```

assuming you want to change the data.frame itself. Because

```
test %>% parse_number(id_numbers)
```

is the same as

```
parse_number(test, id_numbers)
```

and `test` is not a character vector, it is a data.frame, hence you get the error.